# Secure Websockets with Client Certificate Authentication using Twisted

Tags: authentication, websocket, ssl-certificate, twisted

I would like to know if there is an option to implement secure websockets (wss://) and client certificate based authentication with twisted ?

I followed the instructions on http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/ssl.html, in which the setup of a site over https:// and client certificates is described. Using self signed certs, this works fine. However, things get tricky when Websockets come into play.

Running the whole thing in IE 10 works fine. The client authenticates with his certificate and gains access to the site and may open the Websocket. FF and Chrome, however, won't work. Note that webserver and websocket run on the same port.

In my opinion, it seems that IE somehow stores the authentication of the client and uses it as well for the access to the websocket. FF and Chrome somehow treat the websocket as a different ressource for which no authentication has happened before.

Has anybody experienced the same or somewhat similiar issues or maybe implemented a solution for this?

If needed, I can provide my source code so far.

Answer (score 3):

For all interested readers having the same problem, I finally figured it out.
The solution is to set a session id for the ssl context. Then the browser seems to remember the cert authentication even for subresources like websockets.

This should do it:

```
contextFactory = twisted.internet.ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('keys/server.key',
                                                 'keys/server.crt')


ctx = contextFactory.getContext()
ctx.set_verify(
     OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_PEER | OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE,
     verifyCallback
     )
## Since we have self-signed certs we have to explicitly
## tell the server to trust them.
ctx.load_verify_locations("keys/ca.crt")
ctx.set_session_id("id")
```

Lines 1-8 are needed anyway. Whats new is line 9. Here you have to set a session id.

Answer (score 1):

As you've described the issue, this is simply a browser bug, and there's not much you can do about it with Twisted.

Websockets are still, sadly, a somewhat immature technology and bugs like the ones you're seeing are still being worked out.  File bugs against the browsers and hope that they get fixed.

Perhaps you could consider implementing [server-sent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) for non-IE browsers, assuming that the client-cert-auth stuff works for that API / protocol?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However I still hope if there is a solution for this. The concept works fine, as IE 10 shows, however reliability is lacking

Comment: The solution is for the browsers to fix the bugs.  If people like you, who discover the bugs, don't report them, then they're unlikely to ever be fixed.  So, go report them, and link to the bug reports here so others can find them if they locate this question.

Comment: I filed a bug for this issue:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=878715